# Algoritmo de Condições de Fronteira em Python

Tags: python

Não consigo correr isso no meu python, alguém que me possa ajudar? O problema está nas condições de fronteira.

```
for it in range(2,nt):
    uu=u*u;
    uv=u*v;
    vv=v*v;
    hbu=(h-b)*u;
    hbv=(h-b)*v;
    gh=g*h;
    # Avançar o sinal em todo o domínio excepto nas fronteiras
    for ix in range(2,Nx-1):
        for iy in range(2,Ny-1):
            uP[ix,iy] = (1/4. * (u[ix-1,iy] + u[ix+1,iy] + u[ix,iy-1] + u[ix,iy+1])) - dt2dx * (uu[ix+1,iy] - uu[ix-1,iy]) - dt2dy * (uv[ix,iy+1] - uv[ix,iy-1]) + dt2dx * (g*h[ix+1,iy] - g*h[ix-1,iy])
            vP[ix,iy] = (1/4. * (v[ix-1,iy] + v[ix+1,iy] + v[ix,iy-1] + v[ix,iy+1])) - dt2dx * (uv[ix+1,iy] - uv[ix-1,iy]) - dt2dy * (vv[ix,iy+1] - vv[ix,iy-1]) + dt2dy * (gh[ix,iy+1] - gh[ix,iy-1])
            hP[ix,iy] = (1/4. * (h[ix-1,iy] + h[ix+1,iy] + h[ix,iy-1] + h[ix,iy+1])) - dt2dx * (hbu[ix+1,iy] - hbu[ix-1,iy]) - dt2dy * (hbv[ix,iy+1] - hbv[ix,iy-1]) 

  #condições fronteira
    hP[1,:]=hP[2,:];
    hP[Nx,:]=hP[Nx-1,:];
    hP[:,1]=hP[:,2];
    hP[:,Ny]=hP[:,Ny-1];

    uP[1,:]=0;
    uP[Nx,:]=0;
    uP[:,1]=uP[:,2];
    uP[:,Ny]=uP[:,Ny-1];

    vP[1,:]=vP[2,:];
    vP[Nx,:]=vP[Nx-1,:];
    vP[:,1]=0;
    vP[:,Ny]=0;

     # actualizar o sinal
    h[:]=hP[:]; u[:]=uP[:]; v[:]=vP[:];

    hStation[it] = h[ixStation, iyStation]
```

Comment: Qual o resultado esperado e qual o resultado obtido? Pode editar sua pergunta colocando as condições de teste para o algoritmo?

Comment: 3. Especificações técnicas
As condições fronteira são fechadas (não há trocas com o exterior):
x=0, x=Lx: u=0; ∂v/∂x=0; ∂h/∂x=0
y=0, x=Ly: v=0; ∂u/∂y=0; ∂h/∂y=0


Portanto, primeiro fiz a discretização destas 3 equações:

∂u/∂t=−∂/∂x (u2)−∂/∂y (uv) − g*(∂h/∂x) ∂v∂t=−∂∂x(uv)−∂∂y(v2)−g∂h∂y∂h∂t=−∂∂x[(h−b)u]−∂∂y[(h−b)v]

Comment: Contextualize melhor seu problema, explicando o que seu programa se propõe a resolver. Se possível, dê um exemplo de dados de entrada e o resultado correto esperado.